# SSD freezes when trying to copy particular file off of it

Tags: ssd, external-hard-drive, file-transfer

I have an external NVMe SSD formatted as APFS (Encrypted) that I store all my files in. I noticed that it started hanging a lot when trying to use it, so I decided to transfer all the files to another external drive.

This completed successfully, with one exception—a 23.41 GB video file. Whenever I try to copy this over to my other external or to my internal storage, it starts hanging around 6.27 GB copied. When this happens, even if I cancel the file copy operation, the drive still hangs. I need to disconnect the drive and then reconnect it again.

Why is this happening when trying to "read" a file? How do I copy the video file fully to my other external drive?

Comment: Get the manufacturer of the SSD, Find the disk diagnostics app and check the SSD for errors.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try to do that plugged directly into the NVMe slot of my PC's motherboard

Comment: Do you have any larger files that you *were* able to copy? Is file size the problem?

Comment: I recently helped someone recover data from an HS file system - I was surprised that I could see the contents of the drive under Linux but not Mac - even fsck'ing the drive did not work (and the filesystem was clearly corrupt).   Maybe you will have similar luck on APFS?   (See https://www.baeldung.com/linux/apfs-partition-mount )

Comment: Use something like CrystalDiskInfo to read SMART - add screenshot to OP. Symptoms are typical for degrading NAND.